# How to query a Collection after a specific Document in Cloud Firestore with Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following database structure:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- lists (collection)
          |
          --- userId1 (document)
          |     |
          |     --- userLists (collection)
          |             |
          |             --- docKey1 (document)
          |             |     |
          |             |     --- listName: "ListOne"
          |             |     |
          |             |     --- date: January 15, 2018 at 9:56:24 AM UTC+2
          |             |
          |             --- docKey2 (document)
          |                   |
          |                   --- listName: "ListTwo"
          |                   |
          |                   --- date: January 15, 2018 at 9:58:12 AM UTC+2
          |
          --- userId2 (document)
                |
                --- userLists (collection)
                        |
                        --- docKey1 (document)
                        |     |
                        |     --- listName: "ListOne"
                        |     |
                        |     --- date: January 15, 2018 at 9:56:24 AM UTC+2
                        |
                        --- docKey3 (document)
                              |
                              --- listName: "ListThree"
                              |
                              --- date: January 15, 2018 at 9:59:47 AM UTC+2
```

Using this database structure, I can simply query all lists that correspond to a specific user. But, how can I query the database to get all the users that have a specific list?

In this particular case, how to get all the users that have `ListOne` as a list? The result should be: `userId1`

Do I need to duplicate data or is there another way for doing this?

**Edit:**

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- allList
           |
           --- listId1 (collection)
                  |
                  --- userId1 (document)
                  |      |
                  |      --- username: "FirstUser"
                  |      |
                  |      --- //other details
                  |
                  --- userId2 (document)
                         |
                         --- username: "SecondUser"
                         |
                         --- //other details
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to extend a query across multiple subcollections.  A query must be contained within a single collection or subcollection.  So, you're correct in guessing that you'll need to duplicate data in order to perform your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think that it will be a problem if I will store the user object under each `listId` as in my edited post? Basically each user object under `Firestore/users/userId` will be also under `Firestore/allLists/listId/userId`. Is this a good approach?

Comment: There is not really a wrong way to model your data, as long as it satisfies the requirements of your queries.

Comment: It's not really a trick.  He's suggesting that you change your data modeling to remove subcollections from your documents.  If that meets your needs, than feel free to change your modeling.  But all your queries that depend on there being subcollections will have to be changed to suit this new model.

Comment: I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There actually a trick that can be done. Instead of duplicating data, you can add in your `docKey1` document a **`map`**, as Todd Kerpelman said [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdKEhWAV-kE&index=5#t=1m52s). Your document whould look like this:

```
userLists (collection)
    |
    --- docKey1 (document)
          |
          --- listName: "ListOne"
          |
          --- date: January 15, 2018 at 9:56:24 AM UTC+2
          |
          --- users
               |
               --- userId1: true
               |
               --- userId2: true
```

So you can query that particular document to get all the user ids. So in this way you can get a sort what you are asking for.

Comment: I'll go with @Doug's answer but interesting approach. Thanks anyway!